# Use Python to search through output of external .exe

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I am trying to use Python to build a 'wrapper' around an external .exe file. The file, when run, will reply back something like the following:

```
Ignoring profile '\\MachineName\C$\Users\UserName1' (reason: directory inclusion)
Ignoring profile '\\MachineName\C$\Users\UserName2' (reason: directory inclusion)

The following user profiles match the deletion criteria:

\\MachineName\C$\Users\UserName3
```

There could be any number of ignored profiles and any number of matching profiles or none.
What I would like to know is can I get Python to search the output for this exe and then do something else if there is a matching profile?

The code to run the exe is simply:

```
subprocess.Popen(c:\delprof2\DelProf2.exe /l, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Python 2.7
import subprocess

def extractProfiles(source):
  result = []
  for line in source:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line: continue
    result.append(line)

profiles = []
proc = subprocess.Popen(....)
for line in proc.stdout:
  if line.strip() != 'The following user profiles match the deletion criteria:':
    continue
  profiles = extractProfiles(proc.stdout)
  break

# now do something with the profiles
```

Some caveats:

- The above is somewhat brittle in that it's looking for an exact match of when to start remembering profiles ("The following user profiles...") in the output of the subprocess.  If you're not sure it will be exactly that sentence character-for-character, it may be worth using the `re` module and a regular expression to find it.
- The above assumes that the "matching" profiles are the only things that will appear in the subprocess's output after that triggering sentence is seen ("The following user profiles...").  You'd have to do something to detect the delimiter signalling the end of the list of profiles if that is not the case.